unable to read property list from file
Not sure what the exact issue is but when I run npx expo run:ios
it gives me the following error.
error: unable to read property list from file: /Users/jayengineer/Workspace/react_projects/Breached/ios/Breached/Info.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 2.) (in target 'Breached' from project 'Breached')
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Breached</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0.4/string>
      <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
      <string>????</string>
      <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
      <array>
        <dict>
          <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
          <array>
            <string>com.jay754.Breached</string>
          </array>
        </dict>
      </array>
      <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
      <string>1</string>
      <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
      <string></string>
      <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
      <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
        <true/>
      </dict>
      <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
      <string>SplashScreen</string>
      <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
      <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
      </array>
      <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
      <false/>
      <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
      <string>UIStatusBarStyleDefault</string>
      <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
      <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
      </array>
      <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
      <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
      </array>
      <key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
      <string>Light</string>
      <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
      <false/>
    </dict>
  </plist>


You have an error in your XML (missing <):
<string>1.0.4/string>

should be:
<string>1.0.4</string>

You can easily figure out what is wrong with your XML by using:
/usr/bin/plutil -lint info.plist

